# Android create file without saving

Tags: android, caching

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile(""+Common.getMobileNumber(), ".jpg", null);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
fos.write(bos.toByteArray());
```

I do this, but thing is ...when i go to apps, and click on my app... i see that its adding caching. and this particular file is caching, how can i create file without caching/saving.
only need of file for me, is to send it over to server side. 
 
Is there any way i create a object file without saving/caching?

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying you need like a file only in the memory for the particular task like uploading to server. It is very similar to this question to do that. There is a code to create a file in memory.

[Android Creating a memory resident input file that can be attached to an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521471/android-creating-a-memory-resident-input-file-that-can-be-attached-to-an-email)