# How to load Cipher encrypted image file in ImageView without saving to device

Tags: android, image, encryption, imageview

I am creating an application with content security for no one could ever copy the contents and files. I am using cipher to encrypt the image directly from the URL, with out downloading to the device.
Please find my code below.

```
URL url = new URL(images.getImageurl());
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "zerb");
boolean success = true;

if (!folder.exists()){
folder.mkdirs();
}
InputStream fis = connection.getInputStream();
String path = folder.getAbsolutePath() + "images.getImageName + ".jpg";
encryptfile(fis, path, AppConstants.password + images.getContentid() + images.getTopicid())
fis.close();
```

And the cipher encryption Method code is

```
private static boolean encryptfile(InputStream inputStream, String path, String password) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path.concat(".crypt"));
    byte[] key = (AppConstants.salt + password).getBytes("UTF-8");
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    key = sha.digest(key);
    key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while ((b = inputStream.read(d)) != -1) {
        cos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    cos.flush();
    cos.close();
    inputStream.close();
    File encryptedFile = new File(path.concat(".crypt"));
    return (encryptedFile.exists());
}
```

and the decryption code is

```
 public static void decrypt(String path, String password, String outPath) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outPath);
    byte[] key = (AppConstants.salt + password).getBytes("UTF-8");
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    key = sha.digest(key);
    key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while ((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
        fos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    cis.close();
}
```

If I decrypt the image, it will be shown and can be copied from the device.
All I need is to load the encrypted image to an ImageView without saving the decrypted image to the device, so that no one can copy. Please someone help me.

Comment: You might have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10860144/238704) answer to see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `ImageView` can show an in-memory `android.graphics.Bitmap` which can be read in directly from an `InputStream`.

For example, the `decrypt()` method could be adapted to return a `Bitmap` :

```
public Bitmap decrypt(String path, String password) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    byte[] key = (AppConstants.salt + password).getBytes("UTF-8");
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    key = sha.digest(key);
    key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cis);
    cis.close();

    return bitmap;
}
```

(Although it's called `Bitmap`, it's fine to decode a `.jpg` or `.png`).

Then this can be shown in the `ImageView`:

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bitmap = decrypt(path + ".crypt", password);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```